# Does dotnet core have a command line package installer

Tags: nuget, .net-core

It doesn't appear that the current dotnet CLI tools (1.0.1) support installing nugget packages from the command line (unless I'm missing something).  Is there another way to install packages into a .Net Core 1.1 project other than by manually editing the .proj file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dotnet add package` adds a package reference to a project.

Find more information via `dotnet add --help` or `dotnet add package --help`.

If you lack that command, you might not be using the right version of the CLI.

```
> dotnet --version
1.0.1
```